# Jquery Chosen Plugin Styling Lost After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Here is the page (and demos) of the Jquery Chosen Plugin. It's quite handy.

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

---

So my issue is that I'm using a 2 stage input form to collect location information.
The first select menu is for countries. Once a country is selected, the 2nd input field only shows options for the country in field 1. Neato!

here is a live demo of my issue.

http://globatum.com/admin/

You'll notice that the ajax call works but once the 2nd field is returned, the styling is lost! =(

According to the plugin

The select menu must be within a certain html frame

```
    <select data-placeholder="Select City" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2" name="city">
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option class="active-result option"
style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;"

><?=$row['city']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

This technically should work but doesn't.
Any clue as to how to keep the styling after the call?

here is the php page being returned

```
<!--//---------------------------------+
//  Developed by Roshan Bhattarai    |
//  http://roshanbh.com.np           |
//  Contact for custom scripts       |
//  or implementation help.          |
//  email-nepaliboy007@yahoo.com     |
//---------------------------------+-->
<?
#### Roshan's Ajax dropdown code with php
#### Copyright reserved to Roshan Bhattarai - nepaliboy007@yahoo.com
#### if you have any problem contact me at http://roshanbh.com.np
#### fell free to visit my blog http://php-ajax-guru.blogspot.com
?>

<? $country = $_GET['country'];
$link  = mysql_connect("SNIP");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('SNIP');
$query="SELECT city FROM location WHERE country='$country' ORDER BY `city` ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<div class="x">
<br>
<select data-placeholder="Select City" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2" name="city">
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option class="active-result option"><?=$row['city']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Note HTML elements are replaced so you css styles stop working

Comment: @raam86 is there a way to refresh the css to work its magic over the new html?

Comment: CSS always works it's magic. You new elements do not carry the same classes, etc' so CSS does not work on them

Comment: @raam86 what do you propose I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried triggering the `liszt:updated` event when you reload the second list? From the doco

> **Updating Chosen Dynamically**
>   If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "liszt:updated" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.

Edit: in response to the comment about where to put it, I think you'll need to modify the getcity function in the head of the document to be something like:

```
function getCity(country) {
    var strURL="findCity.php?country="+ country;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                    $("#citydiv select").trigger("liszt:updated");
                    ///rest of function
```

This should in theory trigger the event in the right spot after you replace the contents of the city div

Comment: I have no clue as to how I should properly implement that. I saw it in the doc and messed around with it but didn't come up with anything.
I've added the php page being returned. Do I add it there or in the index page?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the style for the chosen-container worked for me

```
.chosen-container input {
width: 100% !important;
}
```